# Redirect in htaccess is adding directory to new URL; not redirecting ExpressionEngine URLs correctly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, indexing, expressionengine

I'm trying to setup a redirect rule for a new ExpressionEngine site.

I'm using the following code placed in my site's `.htaccess` file (the latter section is to [remove index.php from ExpressionEngine's URLs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/remove_index.php.html) - this works):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RedirectMatch 301 ^/2010/example/*$ http://sub.domain.com/new-page/$1

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

A redirect of sort happens, but the URL I get is this:

http://sub.domain.com/new-page2010/example/

I've tried different combinations and it's driving me up the wall!! Any tips on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for Apache's [RedirectMatch Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) expects the use of parenthesis in the RegEx:

> *The supplied regular expression is matched against the URL-path, and
>   if it matches, the server will substitute any parenthesized matches
>   into the given string.*

Using a **RedirectMatch** is equivalent to **Redirect**, but makes use of standard regular expressions, instead of simple prefix matching.

Therefore correcting your example, a valid RedirectMatch Directive would be:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/2010/example/(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/new-page/$1
```

You can tap in the full power of Apache's rewrite engine by using a [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) instead:

```
RewriteRule ^2011/example/(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/new-page/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Depending on what you're wanting to redirect — a single page vs. entire sub-directory — you may need to modify the original URL path in each example.